# mostrar texto mientras se ejecuta el php

Tags: javascript, html5, phpmyadmin, php5

tengo una pagina en php que internamente hace una ejecucion.
este es el codigo del php.

```html
<?php 
require "library/Requests.php";
Requests::register_autoloader();
require "Culqi/culqi.php";
$SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$culqi=new Culqi\Culqi(array('api_key' => $SECRET_KEY));

$charge = $culqi->Charges->create(array(
          "amount" => '1000',
          "currency_code" => "PEN",
          "description" => "Ventas",
          "email" =>  'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
    "installments" => 0,
          "source_id" => 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
        )
);
echo 'Exito';
?>
```

lo que quiero hacer es mostrar una imagen o texto mientras internamente se va ejecutando el php.

Comment: Eso tendrias que hacerlo en javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar spinner y proporcionarles textos en boostrap(css), mientras se procesa tu codigo 
aqui te dejo el link para que puedas darle una revisada
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/spinners/